# Removing duplicate results in a query from 2 tables | SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: php, html, sql, xampp, sqlsrv

May I ask for help regarding this query? `physicianmasterfile.idno` and `CHECKINOUT.userid` have same value in which the data will be compared. The problem is the query have duplicate results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,

physicianmasterfile.idno,
physicianmasterfile.lastname,
physicianmasterfile.firstname,
physicianmasterfile.middlename,
physicianmasterfile.fingerscanno,
CONVERT(DATE, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) AS Date,
CONVERT(TIME(0),CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) AS Time

FROM 
physicianmasterfile,
CHECKINOUT 

WHERE  
CHECKINOUT.userid=physicianmasterfile.fingerscanno AND
CONVERT(DATE, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME()) AND
YEAR(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AND
CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE='I'

ORDER BY CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME
```

I understand that `UNION` will work on this, but I'm not sure on how to approach this as `physicianmasterfile` has multiple column that I need to include in the query, and `CHECKINOUT` I only need 1 column.

This is the sample data for the query above.

[image: EDITING:]

There should be no duplicate results.

This is what I got so far, but no luck.

```
SELECT distinct R.idno, R.lastname, R.firstname, R.middlename, R.fingerscanno,
       LD.CHECKTIME, LD.CHECKTYPE,LD.USERID
FROM physicianmasterfile As R
LEFT JOIN CHECKINOUT AS LD on LD.USERID = R.fingerscanno
WHERE  
       CONVERT(DATE, LD.CHECKTIME) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME()) AND
       YEAR(LD.CHECKTIME) = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AND
       LD.CHECKTYPE='I'
ORDER BY R.idno desc
```

EDIT:

I apologize for the confusion, what I mean is that the query must only show the latest one in every name,lastname,middlename, example: lastname ZZZZ must only show CHECKTIME 28:19.0 and TIME: 5:28:19, lastname NNNN must only show CHECKTIME 57:06.0 and TIME: 7:57:06.. and so on..

Comment: A couple of things I would suggest to make it easier to help you:  1) use an alias for table names to reduce the visual noise, and 2) use ansi style where the join is evident in the FROM clause, I.e., `from physicianmasterfile p inner join checkinout c on p.fingerscanno = c.userid`. This style makes it much easier to intuitively grasp the relationship.

Comment: Also, really need to see schema of the two tables, how they relate. If you can’t guarantee a one to one or many to one relationship, you’re likely to have duplicate records unless you use `group by` and an aggregating function

Comment: Your checkdate is the reason why you are getting duplicate results. You need to perform an aggregate function max() or min() and group by in order to remove duplicate. But if you need all your dates, then you will not be able to remove duplicate

Comment: @pjustindaryl . . . I see no duplicate results.  The first and last columns are different on each row.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I apologize for the confusion, what I mean is that the query must only show the latest one in every name,lastname,middlename, example: lastname ZZZZ must only show CHECKTIME 28:19.0 and TIME: 5:28:19, lastname NNNN must only show CHECKTIME 57:06.0 and TIME: 7:57:06.. and so on..

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's not really duplicate, what I mean is the query must only show the oldest CHECKTIME and Time inputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see all your data, but try changing your FROM and WHERE clauses to:

```
    FROM 
       physicianmasterfile LEFT JOIN CHECKINOUT ON
       physicianmasterfile.fingerscanno = CHECKINOUT.userid
    WHERE  
       CONVERT(DATE, CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = CONVERT(DATE, SYSDATETIME()) AND
       YEAR(CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME) = YEAR(SYSDATETIME()) AND
       CHECKINOUT.CHECKTYPE='I'
```

I didn't test this, so I don't know if it's accurate.

Comment: It still shows duplicate result, all the needed column in ````CHECKINOUT```` is only ````CHECKTIME```` and ````CHECKTYPE````, The rest is from ````physicianmasterfile````.

Comment: I'm currently accessing stackoverflow on my phone,  so I can't really look at much detail,  but it appears that you are trying to get a list of `CHECKINOUT` records, with their associated physician information.  If so, then try reversing the tables in the `JOIN` clause.